# mongodb query to count and group columns

Tags: mongodb

I want to query a mongodb data to check how many products have received comments for each day.

I can express my requirement in SQL query.

```
SELECT Product, Date, count(Product) FROM Exported_Data WHERE Category like "Battery" GROUP by Date,Product;
```

Could anyone help me to write mongodb query for the above query.

my data looks like this in mogodb-

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc057b"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/17/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "other",
    "Comment" : "Samsung galaxy M30s will India only exclusive model and made in India. maybe it will be extend to Sri Lanka. buying not impossible in South East Asia and Europa. We are sad. "
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc057c"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/17/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "other",
    "Comment" : "ema99, 16 Sep 2019hope it is not meant for India only, Uganda also needs thisSouth Africa as well. India I not the only third world country, we need good low cost phones too..."
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc057d"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/17/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "Battery,",
    "Comment" : "Again too large, not 5G, while when next year the supporting transmitters will be ready for 5G testing has already taken place in different cities, the battery is still not interchangeable, so it does not have to be watertight for most. I don't dive with it and I'm not in the rain either. I think more people can also give their opinion better, Samsung needs to listen to the people more and collect these opinions."
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc057e"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/16/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "other",
    "Comment" : "Anonymous, 15 Sep 2019Not going to Indonesia, M30s wlll India only exclusive model, maybe it will be extend to Sti L... moreLet see it bro, because A30s & A50s have been released in indonesia a month ago, Hopefully M30s too"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc057f"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/16/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "other",
    "Comment" : "hope it is not meant for India only, Uganda also needs this"
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc0580"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/16/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "other",
    "Comment" : "Anonymous, 15 Sep 2019Not going to Indonesia, M30s wlll India only exclusive model, maybe it will be extend to Sti L... moreIt will come to Indonesia Malaysia etc soon but price will be different compare to India. "
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc0581"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/16/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "Screen,Battery,",
    "Comment" : "Adexaaz92, 15 Sep 2019Samsung m30s is excellent,the battery is awesome infact the specs is mind blowing but the pric... moreHi sir.... does it have gorilla screen protection?"
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc0582"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/16/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "Screen,",
    "Comment" : "Screen protection is there?"
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc0583"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/15/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "other",
    "Comment" : "Anonymous, 12 Sep 201916K is the price and it's a much better value proposition when compared to chinese brands like... moreDon't worry ,it won't cost less than 16,999 . You can take this as official price."
}

/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc0584"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/15/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "Battery,",
    "Comment" : "Samsung m30s is excellent,the battery is awesome infact the specs is mind blowing but the price needs some adjustment to make more sales, so samsung pls keep it up,thank you. "
}

/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc0585"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/15/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "other",
    "Comment" : "This phone is expected to replace A50, hence it will be priced between the current M30 and A50. Because the A50s price is more than the existing A50 series..."
}

/* 12 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d80bf6043fdfd6874bc0586"),
    "Product" : "Samsung Galaxy M30s",
    "Date" : "09/15/2019",
    "Thread" : "https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m30s-reviews-9818p1.php",
    "Category" : "other",
    "Comment" : "Sandeep, 15 Sep 2019M30 s have gorilla glass ? I think they should skip on that and just go for in house glass protection because they are just as potent, if not more, than the proprietary protection available in market and it will help then save costs and pass it on to customers"
}
```

expecting result like below-

Samsung Galaxy M30s 9/3/2019    Battery 3
Samsung Galaxy M30s 9/4/2019    Battery 5
Samsung Galaxy M30s 9/5/2019    Battery 2
Samsung Galaxy M30s 9/6/2019    Battery 1

Comment: check this [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JMlxBoPUDG0)

Comment: As per your question you want group by with 'Comment' field. 
And provided sql query  has group by product,date with where condition on 'Category' field. 
Your dummy data has only two records for condition  "Category" : "Battery,".  and your expected result has something else. 

Can you please verify your question first?

In mean time you can also try following query with category condition,


db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {"Category": "Battery,",}},{$group: {_id: {dateTemp: "$Date",productTemp: "$Product"},numberofPostID: {$sum: 1}}},{$sort: {numberofPostID: -1}}])

Comment: No.. not group by 'Comment', comment field is not required in result for me. Group by should be by Date first and then by product.. like how it is done in SQL.. However your code helped me to get required results with little modification.  

db.getCollection('Exported_Data').aggregate([{$match: {"Category": "Battery,",}},{$group: {_id: {dateTemp: "$Date",productTemp: "$Product", categoryTemp: "$Category"},numberofPostID: {$sum: 1}}},{$sort: {numberofPostID: -1}}])

Comment: Glad that my comment helped you, It would be great if you can upvote the my comment. Cheers :)